# How to check if app has been loaded from Google Play or "unknown source"

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way for an android application to check if it has been installed straight from Google Play (ex-Android Market) or manually installed from some other source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can register a BroadcastReseiver which will be triggered at install time if installation happened from Market. Try to google "android receiver install_referrer".